# awk to retrieve the first field report from atq

Tags: bash, awk

I am learning awk to advance my skills and tried

```
$ atq | awk "{print $1}" 
28  Wed Oct 31 10:23:00 2018
27  Tue Oct 30 21:20:00 2018
25  Tue Oct 30 21:19:00 2018
29  Wed Oct 31 10:42:00 2018
26  Tue Oct 30 21:20:00 2018
20  Tue Oct 30 18:25:00 2018
30  Wed Oct 31 10:59:00 2018
32  Wed Oct 31 21:03:00 2018
23  Tue Oct 30 18:28:00 2018
31  Wed Oct 31 13:58:00 2018
19  Tue Oct 30 15:43:00 2018
21  Tue Oct 30 18:27:00 2018
```

It did not work as I expected, but it's relatively easy to work small programs together

```
$ atq | cut -f 1
28
27
25
29
26
20
30
32
23
31
19
21
```

How could I retrieve the first field using awk?

Comment: You need single quotes around the awk commands.

Answer (score 8):

Try the below,

```
atq | awk '{print $1}'
```

The single quotes stops the shell from expanding `$1` to the shell's first positional parameter.

Comment: great, could you please elaborate the reasons.

Comment: An alternative would be `atq | awk "{print \$1}"` - sometimes there are reasons you want the double quote, and in that case, escaping the `$` is necessary. Contrived example: `prefix="foo: "; atq | awk "{print $prefix, \$1}"`. Granted, that would normally be better accomplished using `awk`s `-v variable=...` syntax, but it can still be useful sometimes...

Comment: @twalberg No, you don't generally want the shell to interpolate the `awk` code. To use a shell variable in an `awk` program, import it using `-v var="$var"` or `export` it and access it through `ENVIRON["var"]`.  Using single quotes around `awk` code is _always_ possible and always what you'd want to do.